# Vimperator Scroll

Tags: vimperator

I have recently installed vimperator in firefox. The problem I face while using it is that when I am trying to scroll the feeds in Google reader, it actually scrolls through all the feeds that I follow. As in there are two different scrolls on the page and so how do i tell it to use the the scroll which I want.. I have gone through websites but still I wasn't able to get how should switch between scroll selections. Can anyone help on finding the Keyboard shortcut for the right frame to scroll?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually switched to [Pentadactyl](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/pentadactyl/) because of this. Using vimperator it is possible to achieve this (though I'd have to look up how), but pentadactyl added better support.

I have

```
set passkeys+=google.com/reader/:j,k,v,<CR>,r
```

in my config, which sets any url that matches `google.com/reader/` to pass the keys j, k, v, return, and r through to the page rather than handling them.

Other than that the two are very similar projects with very similar goals, I had no problem switching. Pentadactyl is a fork by some of the original developers of vimperator. I assume they had a good old open source forking out at some point.

Comment: Pentadactyl is amazing but i was looking for an answer in which i can focus particular frame for scrolling in any website. Could you help me out in that?